# Display SQL columns values on individual rows using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I am using the following MySQL/Joomla database query to return results from the table.

```
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('FormId', 'FieldName', 'FieldValue')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_submission_values'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('FormId') . ' = ' . $db->quote('5'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('SubmissionId') . ' = ' . $db->quote('4'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('FieldName') . ' = ' . $db->quote('documents'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

The data that is stored in the documents "FieldName" column are checkbox values. How would I go about selecting each individual checkbox value from the column and display it on it's own line using PHP and HTML? Currently I am using the following PHP/HTML to display the results.

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $formLayout .= "<div>" . $row->FieldValue . "</div>";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So you're getting results from the database for the checkboxes that were true, but not the ones that were false?

Comment: Use if statements, or ternary operators, or an array along with the form post data to control your output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to ensure all the fields have a result to display, you could try the following approach after you run the query:

```
//create an array that contains all the fields you want to ensure are  
// displayed (in the order you want them to appear) and set the default
// values to FALSE
$results=array_fill_keys(
    array('documents',
        'pictures',
        'another_field',
        'something_else'
         ), false);

//update any values that were found in database
foreach($rows as $row) {
     $results[$row->FieldName]=$row->FieldValue;   
}

//generate the html
foreach($results as $fieldName=>$fieldValue) {
    $formLayout .= sprintf('<div>The `%s` box was %s</div>',$fieldName,$fieldValue?'checked':'not checked');
}
```

Comment: This would work, but the issue may be with how the database table is setup. "FieldName" contains the name of the form fields and "FieldValue" contains the form fields values. I only want to select the documents "FieldName" and retrieve the checkbox values stored in the "FieldValue" column. Check out this screenshot to see how the table is structured [link](http://imgur.com/uGkAZNW). Would the code you posted work for this scenario? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, it should. I changed the example FieldName values to be a little more clear on the intended usage.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have implemented the code, but the core issue remains. The "FieldValue" values from the documents "FieldName" column are still grouped together as one single value. I am needing to "break out" each individual checkbox value and display it in it's own DIV. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$query` and running it manually through your database admin tool (e.g., phpMyAdmin) to make sure the `$rows` result is in the expected format?

OR use a tool like PHP dBug (http://dbug.ospinto.com/) to dump the value of $rows to the screen?

Comment: Yes, I have run the SQL query through phpMyAdmin and I am getting the returned results that I am expecting. This is the query `SELECT 'FormId', 'FieldName', 'FieldValue' FROM 'vru2q_rsform_submission_values' WHERE 'FormI' = '5' AND 'SubmissionId' = '4' AND ('FieldName' = 'firstname' OR 'FieldName' = 'documents')` This issue is taking the documents "FieldValue' values and displaying each item on it's own line. They are checkbox values that need to be treated as regular text inside a DIV. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the behavior I would expect, which is why I iterated over `$ rows` and combined the seoarate rows into `$ results`. If you dump `$ results` does it not have the structure you want?

Comment: Here is what comes from the var_dump: `array(1) {
  ["documents"]=>
  string(115) "Most Recent Financial Statement
Management Agreement
Bylaws
Insurance Policy
Most Recent Board of Directors Minutes"
}` This is the information I need, but I need to have each document name in it's own DIV. Using a modified version of your foreach, all of the documents are displayed in one DIV. `foreach($results as $fieldName=>$fieldValue) {
    $formLayout .= '<div>'.$fieldValue.'</div>';
}`

Comment: Wait, is `"Most Recent Financial Statement Management Agreement Bylaws Insurance Policy Most Recent Board of Directors Minutes"` the value that is stored in the database itself? If so, then I misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, these are the checkbox values that are stored in the "FieldValue" column. Most Recent Financial Statement, Management Agreement, Bylaws, Insurance Policy and Most Recent Board of Directors Minutes are the individual checkbox item values that are stored together in the table.

Comment: Then you'll need to add some sort of delimiter to the data somehow. You could use a semicolon and then call `$fieldValues=explode(';',$fieldValue)` to get the headers into an array called `$fieldValues`. Or you could use `json_encode` and `json_decode` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I have got it figured out. My PHP skills are novice at best, but here is the code I have used. `foreach($rows as $row) {
    $documentsArray[] = $row->FieldValue;
}

$documents = implode(',', $documentsArray);
$values    = explode(',', $documents);` and `foreach($values as $v) {
    $formLayout .= '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
}` to access the array values and loop through them. Feel free to offer suggestions to clean up or optimize the code. Thank you for your assistance.